# Mysql join not showing all records

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am using Php with join, I have two tables ("services" and "service_detail"), I want to get all services
but want to know which service selected or notselected by vendor

Here is my services table strcture

```
id          service_name        image
1           Abc                 abc.jpg
2           xyz                 xyz.jpg
3           OPS                 ops.jpg
4           tys                 tys.jpg
5           byp                 byp.jpg
```

Here is my services_detail table strcutre

```
id          vendor_id       service_id      price
1           101             1               50
2           101             2               70
3           101             3               80
4           101             4               30
5           102             1               70
6           102             2               40
...
```

I tried with following query but showing only selected services, but i want to get all services with parameter ( selected or notselected)
Where i am wrong ? Here is my query

```sql
SELECT sd.vendor_id, sd.service_id, sd.price, s.service_name, s.image
FROM services_detail sd
LEFT JOIN services s
ON sd.service_id = s.id
WHERE sd.vendor_id = '101'
```

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave: you are right , by mistake i typed"1" its "101", actually problem is i cant get all services, right now i am getting which services selected by vendor, but i want complete list with parameter which services is taken or not taken by vendor

Comment: Can you please give an example of the data you want out of this query? Your question isn't making much sense at the moment

Comment: With `RIGHT JOIN services s`, it will list services even though there isn't a `services_detail` row, all `sd.` values will be null.

Comment: @Phil: i want result like following way

id  service_name  image  vendor_id  price status
1  abc     abc.jpg  101    50  selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your where clause to be `AND` in `ON` clause:

**AND sd.vendor_id = '101'**

And interchange tables in join to get all servcies

```
SELECT sd.vendor_id, sd.service_id, sd.price, s.service_name, s.image, 
IF (sd.vendor_id is not null, 'Opted', 'Not opted') as status
FROM services s
LEFT JOIN services_detail sd
ON sd.service_id = s.id AND sd.vendor_id = '101';
```

In simple words, when there is a where clause including filters on table of `Left Join` then it will act like `INNER JOIN` not `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: your query showing all services of all vendors but i want to get only services of vendor number "101"

Comment: @deepikaaggarwal could you create a SqlFiddle ? Thats what I understood with your question "You need all services". Sorry if I misunderstood. It seems then your query should work and return only service of vendor 101.

Comment: yes you are right i want "all services" with status ( services taken or not) , thats it

Comment: Ok, I have updated query. Switching tables from `from` and `left join` Could you confirm now ? @deepikaaggarwal

Comment: Sidiqui: now showing all services and image ( service_name and image) but rest of columns ( vendor_id,service_id,price) showing "NULL"

Comment: Yeah, because they are not opted by that vendor. so this is how left join works.

Comment: no there should be some record because vendor taken some services but right now showing all rows "NULL", means query is not correct

Comment: Nope, the vendor records will be avialble for service 1,2,3 and 4 and rest services will not have a vendor record.

Comment: Look, I did tested with 2 records (one selected and one notselected) https://i.stack.imgur.com/htIPJ.png

If still that is not suffiecient? then please add expected outcome in your question.

Comment: yes so your query should show vendor_id,service_id,price for service (1,2,3,4) but its showing "NULL" for all records

Comment: Did you tried latest query ? seriousaly ? It should and it is retuning same.

Comment: its working now :) but how can i get status ? ( want to know which service is taken and which is not ) ?

Comment: Added one more column for you. Enjoy :)